# How to put string value between quotes in datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

how to put a string between quotes in datetimepicker.

I'm trying to solve the below problem.

my code doesn't work.

my code string hrs2 value doesn't work.

```
var dt = new Date();  
var hrs = dt.getHours()+4;  
var hrs2 = '"' + 23 + ":00" + '"';  
alert(hrs2);  

$('#starttime').datetimepicker({  
    step:30,  
    minDate:0,  
    minTime: hrs2,  
    format:'Y-m-d H:i:0',  
    beforeShowDay: available,  
});
```

how to store a value between quotes.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Dhanil Dinesan alert output "23:00", but minTime function doesnt works, i tried also '23:00' single quotes too

Comment: you need to show "23:00" in DateTime picker right? when it will be shown? when the user tries to add something?

Comment: $(document).ready i put, to initialize 23:00 as minTime

Comment: whats the name of your plugin?

Comment: so sorry, i use xdsoft_timepicker